# What is this idiom called?

Tags: c++, idioms

Suppose I have an `Iterable` interface:

```
template<typename T>
struct Iterable
{
  virtual bool MoveNext() = 0;
  virtual T& GetCurrent() = 0;
};
```

And then I have a class which implements the `Iterable` interface.  Call it `FileList`.  It represents a list of files on a `FAT16` system.  Because of limited memory on my micro controller instead of `FileList` actually storing a list of files when the `GetCurrent` is called it grabs the file from the SD card, which it is accessing.

So my question is:

What is the idiom I just preformed called (if it even is an idiom that exists)?

Comment: If I understand correctly, it seems to be a Lazy Iterator.

Comment: If you're writing c++ the name for this idiom is "an error". If you model your iterators on the concepts in the standard library, you will be able to use them with all standard algorithms. That has to be a win.

Comment: @RichardHodges Seeing as I am on a micro controller (as mentioned in the question) I do not have access to the c++ standard library as it would eat up all of my memory.

Comment: @DarthRubik: You're writing microcontroller code and using virtual functions instead of templates. Are you sure that's a good idea?

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes I realize that it could end up biting me, but I have judiciously weighed both sides, and decided this is the way I am going (and I don't think this is the place to argue that point)

Comment: @DarthRubik standard algorithms are incredibly efficient in both memory and cpu cycles. If you're avoiding them for those reasons, this would be making a decision on the basis of poor information.

Comment: @RichardHodges There is no implementation that will fit on my micro controller (because including the std library requires you to include **all** of it....not just what you need, unless there is a source for the std library out there, but I would rather just implement an iterable class myself)

Comment: @DarthRubik here's one implementation: https://gcc.gnu.org/libstdc++/

Comment: The Concept itself is still an iterator. If you look at `Iterable`, the client only knows that it can iterate over a container and get the current value. However. the implementation is simply known Lazy Evaluation. I don't think there is a point in finding an idiom that combines the two ideas together, because lazy evaluation could be used with pretty much every Concept.

Comment: @RichardHodges Another reason I cannot use it is that too much of the standard uses dynamic memory allocation (a big no no in embedded systems), and I do not want to unwittingly use a class that uses dynamic allocation....so I write all of it myself, which means that I need not worry......like I said I don't believe this is the place to argue what I should be using on a micro controller.

Comment: @DarthRubik: I think you need to recognize the difference between standard library containers (which dynamically allocate memory) and standard library *algorithms*, which allocate nothing. The standard library is not an all-or-nothing type thing; you can use the parts that work for you and ignore the rest.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes it's called a Generator.

Comment: Is that always an answer, or just sometimes?

Comment: If you have anything to back up your claim, that would be nice

Comment: @KABoissonneault, why are you asking?